# Symfony: Loop does not work in twig template

Tags: php, symfony

I have created e simple function in a repository and passed it to the controller like this

**CONTROLLER**

```
...

public function repositoryAction() {

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$user = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findAllOrderedByName();



return $this->render('dashboard/repository.html.twig',array('user'=>$user));


}
```

With the line of code below

```
return $this->render('dashboard/repository.html.twig',array('user'=>$user));
```

I am passing the array to the view.

Here is the loop in the twig template

```
{% for user in profile %}
{{ profile.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

An this is the error:

```
Variable "profile" does not exist in dashboard/repository.html.twig at line 44
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Basics. At least you'll know the meaning of the array given to the render function. Anton deserves an upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think you should do:

```
{% for profile in user %}
{{ profile.name }}
{% endfor %}
```